# Firefox : Import bookmarks from one firefox browser to another in different laptop

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, import

I have two laptops on which firefox is installed. I want to merge the bookmarks. How can I achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the FAQ in firefox? You could export either one of FF's bookmarks as HTML and import it from the other FF. The imported ones should now appear in a folder. **After this you can register to sync so you don't need to do this often.

Comment: the file I want to import is in json format

Comment: Same question answered here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/970691